# how to call a different comment folder script into my form using php? is that possible?

Tags: php

i want to know, Is that possible to call a folder(which posses a comment script) into my php form??

Alright, lets say i have one form for php:

```
<body>
<div id="comment_header">

</div>

<div id="right_box">
<p style="text-align: center;">Today's Top faces</p>
    <a href="index.php?logout">Logout</a>
</div>
</body>
```

Now, i want to call my comment script folder into `<div id="comment_header">` is that possible ?? can you explain me with an example, i would be very thankful for you ;)

Thank you in advanced!!

**EDITED:**

I have this [pic](http://postimg.org/image/8jvvyarct/).

I have on this a called `comment-script` folder now i want to call this comment script into my form i mean i want to implement this comment box into my website with particular form.

So, can you tell the way to call this comment script folder into my form.

Comment: Please talk more about that folder you want to call. The way to do this might differ greatly depending on what you have in the folder.

Comment: alright, see my edit ;)

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Same here but I'll try. Considering there is a Logout link, you want to include another file's script into here without copying the whole thing over here? In that case, [PHP include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) will do.

`include 'comment_script/view/index.php';`

Comment: really? actually i have downloaded a comment box script, and it's working when i check, and i provided you a pic as you can see there .. i don't want to modify my form file and i want directly to call this script into my form so as you suggested that `php include` would work well.. so, would it be capable to call the `form design and css code` into my `logged-in.php` file?

Comment: load css/ js files correctly and include php file then this will work

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way would be an include:

```
<?php

include_once("relative/path/to/my/script.php");

?>
```